# SSRS combination column and line chart - line width

Tags: reporting-services

I've got a chart in SSRS where I have both line and column values. 
Is there any way the line can extend out to the extreme left and right of the corresponding column for the month? 
The Green line is the target and the orange columns are the Utilisation figures for the months

[image]

I've tried Strip Lines but creating the IIF expressions to capture the filtering is too much pain and you can't get varying results by Month.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to stick your line on the secondary X axis and then play with the settings of that axis. Once you get the settings like you want them you can hide the secondary X axis from the chart area.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, there are no settings there on the secondary axis to effect this.